# How should pip for Python 3 be set up on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: python, 16.10, python3, pip

I have run the following to install pip for Python 3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

I am expecting an executable called something like `pip3` to be accessible now, but it is not. When I do an `updatedb; mlocate pip3`, I do not find such an executable. How should I proceed?

Comment: The package `python3-pip` contains the executable file `/usr/bin/pip3`. If the installation was successful and did not show any error messages, that file must be there.

Comment: try which pip3, lets see if it shows up some thing.